# Compact CTE syntax for on the fly lookup table, DB2 or SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

I'm creating a dynamic SQL query and building some lookup tables on the fly in a CTE. The syntax I came up with is quite verbose and I wonder if there is a more compact way to express this. The lookup tables are CTEs created in code and can vary from query to query. Hope this example makes it clear:

```
WITH lookuptable1 (code, desc)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT 18, 'Oakland' from Sysibm.sysdummy1 union 
    select 19, 'New York City' from Sysibm.sysdummy1 union 
    select 20, 'San Francisco' from  Sysibm.sysdummy1
)  
, lookuptable2 (code2, desc2) as
(  
    SELECT 18, 'CA' from Sysibm.sysdummy1 union 
    select 19, 'NY' from Sysibm.sysdummy1 union 
    select 20, 'AZ' from  Sysibm.sysdummy1 union 
    select 22, 'RI' from  Sysibm.sysdummy1  
)  
select user.userid,  code, desc, code2, desc2
from USER 
inner join lookuptable1 on user.city = lookuptable1.code
left outer join lookuptable2 on user.state = code2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server, instead of

```
SELECT 18, 'Oakland' FROM Sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION
SELECT 19, 'New York City' FROM Sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION
SELECT 20, 'San Francisco' FROM Sysibm.sysdummy1
```

You can use the `VALUES` clause

```
SELECT id, Label
FROM (
VALUES
    (18, 'Oakland'),
    (19, 'New York City'),
    (20, 'San Francisco')
) as X (id, Label)
```

Which doesn't look much more compact here, but will for more values.

And if using `UNION` you could further improve it as

```
SELECT 18, 'Oakland' UNION ALL
SELECT 19, 'New York City' UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 'San Francisco'
```

So no need to select from a table if you aren't using it. And when unioning you would use `union all` not `union` because you know in advance you want all rows, whereas `union` includes a de-duplication stage which often causes performance issues.

Comment: your answer is good, but the `values` is not standard sql sintax... I wouldn't bet it works on db2 as well as sql server

Comment: @JaimeDrq yeah, but, OP said *OR* not *BOTH* - so maybe it helps.

Comment: Sure it helps... I just made the comment because the `Sysibm.sysdummy1` table is kind of the `DUAL` table in Oracle in DB2, so here we have a mix...

Comment: VALUES as above works in 2 of 3 Db2 products: DB2 for IBM i and Db2 for LUW. But not in DB2 for Z/OS.

Comment: thanks @MarkBarinstein, good to know the detail . Luckily I didn't bet

Comment: I need both DB2 and SQL server syntax, but they can be different.

Comment: I tried to follow your example for sQL server but I get syntax errors. can you paste the entire sql statement like I did in my question? Also for DB2 I have to use sysdummy.sysibm1 it does not allow the select without a from. I do need answers for both db2 and sql server, but I expected them to be the same, they do not have to be for my need.

Answer (score 0):

Dale K's answer works for me, the values clause works in both DBs. I am only answering to post the full query here (The correct answer only shows partial syntax and for others I wanted to post the full query)

```
WITH  lookuptable1 (id, label) as
(select id, label 
from (
values 
    (0, 'Oakland'),
    (218, 'New York City'),
    (121, 'San Francisco')
 ) as X (id, Label))
, 
lookuptable2 (id, label) as
(select id, label 
from (  
 values
    ( 0, 'CA' ), 
    ( 97, 'NY' ),
    ( 316, 'AZ' ),
    ( 296, 'RI' )
) as Y (id,label)) 
select hji_id, name, lookuptable1.id, lookuptable1.label, lookuptable2.id, lookuptable2.label
from tt_hji 
inner join lookuptable1 on ry_id = lookuptable1.id
left outer join lookuptable2 on zone_id = lookuptable2.id
```